# Resampling a pandas dataframe in long format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in long format with speed data with varying time sampling intervals and frequencies for two observations locations (A and B). If I apply the resample method to get the average daily value, I get the average values of all variables for a given time interval (and not the average value for speed, distance).

Does anyone know how to resample the dataframe and keep the 2 locations but produce daily average speed data?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dti = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='15min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = dti)

# Average speed in miles per hour
df['Location'] = 'A'
df['speed'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=60, size=len(df.index))
# Distance in miles (speed * 0.5 hours)


dti2 = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2016-06-05', freq='30min')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = dti2)
df2['Location'] = 'B'
df2['speed'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=60, size=len(df2.index))

df = df.append(df2)

df2 = df.resample('d', on='index').mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `resample`:

```
>>> df.groupby("Location").resample("D").mean().reset_index(0)

           Location      speed
2015-01-01        A  29.114583
2015-01-02        A  27.083333
2015-01-03        A  31.135417
2015-01-04        A  30.354167
2015-01-05        A  29.427083
            ...        ...
2016-06-01        B  33.770833
2016-06-02        B  28.979167
2016-06-03        B  29.812500
2016-06-04        B  31.270833
2016-06-05        B  42.000000
```

If you instead want separate columns for A and B, you can use `unstack`:

```
>>> df.groupby("Location").resample("D").mean().unstack(0)
                speed           
Location            A          B
2015-01-01  29.114583  29.520833
2015-01-02  27.083333  27.291667
2015-01-03  31.135417  30.375000
2015-01-04  30.354167  31.645833
2015-01-05  29.427083  26.645833
              ...        ...
2016-06-01        NaN  33.770833
2016-06-02        NaN  28.979167
2016-06-03        NaN  29.812500
2016-06-04        NaN  31.270833
2016-06-05        NaN  42.000000
```